# How to access JavaScript variable in HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access JavaScript variable in the `href` attribute of anchor tag.

JavaScript Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function fun(ReqTextbox) 

{ 

var queueData =document.getElementById(ResTextbox).value; 
//some more code 

} 
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<body> 
    <input type="text" value="<%=dynamicValue%>" id="<%=dynamicId%>"/> 
    <a href="servlet?variablename="<%Eval(queueData)%>" onclick=fun('<%=dynamicvalue%>');>LINK</a>     
</body>
```

I know that I am going to wrong at `variablename="<%Eval(queueData)%>"`.

Can someone please help me how to access and pass JavaScript variable as a query string parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think you made a typo :

```
function fun(ReqTextbox) { 
    var queueData = document.getElementById(ResTextbox).value; 
    //some more code
}
```

You get `ReqTextbox` parameter but you use `ResTextbox`. Then, since Javascript is client-sided, you have to manually update the href tag using `href` attribute. So your function would be like :

```
function fun(ReqTextbox) { 
    var queueData = document.getElementById(ReqTextbox).value; 
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').href = "servlet?variablename=" + queueData;
    //some more code
}
```

And give your anchor tag an id, `myAnchor` in my example.

Comment: then wat should be written in href attribute of <a> tag in HTML code

Comment: @SudhakarByna At first, you can write `href="#"`. It'll be updated when the `fun` function is called.

Comment: @ Nathan P, If I wanted to add one more variable name and its dynamic value in the href attribute of the above code you have suggested, can u please tell me how the concatenation can be done

Comment: @SudhakarByna JavaScript's concatenation can be achieved with `+` operator. Just assure that the variable is in the scope of the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
Modify HTML code as given below - 

<body> 
<input type="text" value="<%=dynamicValue%>" id="<%=dynamicId%>"/>
<div id="example2"> 
<a href="servlet?variablename="<%Eval(queueData)%>" onclick=fun('<%=dynamicvalue%>');>LINK</a> </div>
</body> 

Use this to pass query string - 

$("#example2 a").attr("href", url + "?variablename=" + queueData);
```

Comment: OP doesn't seem to use jQuery

Comment: But it is not allowing the following stmt.

Comment: <a href="servlet?variablename="<%Eval(queueData)%>" onclick=fun('<%=dynamicvalue%>');>LINK</a> </div>

Comment: Try by replacing existing anchor tag with simple anchor tag like this
<a href="" />

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly inside **fun()** function try to use:

```
var queueData = this.getAttribute('id');
```

That way you will get id value when runnning onclick() function.